# How to combine time base polling with awaitable Task

Tags: c#, timer, async-await, polling

I implemented already a polling-worker based on Timer. As example you can think of `TryConnect` on the client side -- I call `TryConnect` and it will connect eventually in some time. It handles multiple threads, if connecting is in the process already all subsequent `TryConnect` returns immediately without any extra action. Internally I simply create a timer and in intervals I try to connect -- if the connection fails, I try again. And so on.

Small downside is it is "fire&forget" pattern and now I would like to combine it with "async/await" pattern, i.e. instead calling:

```
client.TryConnect(); // returns immediately
// cannot tell if I am connected at this point
```

I would like to call it like this:

```
await client.TryConnect();
// I am connected for sure
```

How can I change my implementation to support "async/await"? I was thinking about creating empty `Task` (just for `await`), and then complete it with `FromResult`, but this method **creates** a new task, it does not complete given instance.

*For the record, current implementation looks like this (just a sketch of the code):*

```
public void TryConnect()
{
   if (this.timer!=null)
   {
     this.timer = new Timer(_ => tryConnect(),null,-1,-1);
     this.timer.Change(0,-1); 
   }
}
private void tryConnect()
{
   if (/*connection failed*/)
     this.timer.Change(interval,-1);
   else
     this.timer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lacking a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to offer any specific suggestions. Given what you've written, it's *possible* what you're looking for is `TaskCompletionSource`. For example:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs;

public async Task TryConnect()
{
   if (/* no connection exists */)
   {
     if (_tcs == null)
     {
       this.timer = new Timer(_ => tryConnect(),null,-1,-1);
       this.timer.Change(0,-1); 
       _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
     }

     await _tcs.Task;
   }
}

private void tryConnect()
{
   if (/*connection failed*/)
     this.timer.Change(interval,-1);
   else
   {
     _tcs.SetResult(true);
     _tcs = null;
     this.timer = null;
   }
}
```

Notes:

- Your original code example would retry the connection logic if `TryConnect()` is called again after a connection is made. I expect what you really want is to also check for the presence of a valid connection, so I modified the above slightly to check for that. You can of course remove that part if you actually always want to attempt a new connection, even if one already exists.
- The code sets `_tcs` to `null` immediate after setting its result. Note though that any code awaiting or otherwise having stored the `Task` value for the `_tcs` object will implicitly reference the current `_tcs` object, so it's not a problem to discard the field's reference here.
- There is no non-generic `TaskCompletionSource`. So for scenarios where you just need a `Task`, you can use the generic type with a placeholder type, like `bool` as I've done here or `object` or whatever. I could've called `SetResult(false)` just as well as `SetResult(true)`, and it wouldn't matter in this example. All that matters is that the `Task` is completed, not what value is returned.
- The above uses the `async` keyword to make `TryConnect()` an async method. IMHO this is a bit more readable, but of course does incur slight overhead in the extra `Task` to represent the method's operation. If you prefer, you can do the same thing directly without the `async` method:

```cs
public Task TryConnect()
{
   if (/* no connection exists */)
   {
     if (_tcs == null)
     {
       this.timer = new Timer(_ => tryConnect(),null,-1,-1);
       this.timer.Change(0,-1); 
       _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
     }

     return _tcs.Task;
   }

   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```